# Codeigniter: using datagrid

Tags: codeigniter, datagrid, jqgrid, flexigrid

i'm looking for implement datagrid with CI, better if using ajax.

Searching on Google i've found many tutorial and discussion on how to use **Flexigrid-4-CI** or **jqGrid**, anyway i'm still confused on which one could offer more flexibility.

For example, is it possible to set more than one field to filter results with Flexigrid? Besides extending my search i found other libraries such as [CarboGrid](http://carbogrid.sourceforge.net/) or [datagrid-CI](http://code.google.com/p/ci-datagrid/).

Does anyone tried that stuff? What's your suggestion? CarboGrid looks really interesting...

Comment: Just tried CI-datagrid lib. Plan datagrid, no ordening function and no ajax. Besides i haven't find docs on the web.

Comment: Have you looked at datatables?

Comment: There is a good example here: http://www.gensale.net/codeigniter-datagrids/ Which is real easy to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using datatables, simple, clean, and fast under 1000 rows.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to use datatables... the docs seems clear and complete, do you know any other good source to learn on this?

Comment: I am using datatables too, I tried with 10K+ rows in FF and was working great

Answer (score 3):

I have found a few actively on development

[phpGrid](http://phpgrid.com/example/phpgrid-and-codeigniter-integration/) - A lot of features
[SmartGrid](http://www.techlaboratory.net/smartgrid) - Simple grid with bootstrap support
[Grocery CRUD Datagrid](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/about) - A framework with Datagrid